# How do you use httpx AsyncClient with pytest in fastapi?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I have tried everything I've been able to find, but I can't get async tests working.

I get `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` running `TestClient` (which makes sense based on the docs), but I get `httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` using `httpx AsyncClient`.

I have a simple test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
async def async_client() -> Generator:
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://0.0.0.0') as client:
        yield client

@pytest.mark.asyncio@mock.patch('apps.core.views.requests.get', new=mocked_get_request)
async def test_get_non_json_response(async_client: AsyncClient):
    response = await async_client.get("/mymedia")
    assertEqual(response.json()['error']['message']['message'], 'Not json')
```

Where  `/media` is:

```
@app.get('/mymedia')
async def my_media(request: Request, cache: RedisCacheBackend = Depends(redis_cache)):
    return await my_media_ep(request, cache=cache)
```

`my_media_ep` is a long function with multiple async api calls.

I have also tried it as suggested in the [Async Tests docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/), but get the same error.

Any suggestions or examples?